# Too large an array of Mat objects causes Seg Fault

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, vector, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat test[100000];
    std::cout << "testing" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Returns a seg fault. I couldn't find any information regarding this setup. I can't think why it would mess up the memory as I've not initialised the Mats with anything (hence they're all empty, and 4K images which use significantly more memory have no issue).

Comment: Most likely that is because you can't squeeze `100000` of `Mat` objects on the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is convert the array of `Mat`s (`cv::Mat[]`) into a vector of `Mat`s (std::vector). I won't pretend to understand why, but I would guess vectors have better memory management going on under the hood.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

int main()
{
    int size = 100000;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> test;
    test.resize(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {test[i] = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 256, CV_32F);}
    std::cout << "testing" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't need the `size` variable or the separate resizing, just `std::vector<cv::Mat> test(100000);` and then use either `test.size()` or iterators or range-based `for` loops.

Comment: As for the "memory management under the hood", vectors allocate their "array" of the heap. Essentially it's doing `new cv::Mat[100000]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I intentionally made it more verbose than necessary such that newer programmers may more easily understand it, but thanks for the explanations =)